# Can any sequence of consecutive integers be realized as winding numbers?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, discrete-geometry, plane-geometry

For a closed plane curve $C$, define its sequence of winding numbers to
be the sorted list of the winding numbers of each of the distinct regions
of the plane demarcated by $C$.
For example, this curve (if I've calculated correctly) has sequence
$001111223 = 0^2 1^4 2^2 3$.

---

[image: WindingNumbers]

---

A winding number sequence must include $0$ for the unbounded region of the plane.
I am wondering if there are any other restrictions:

> ***Q***. Can any winding sequence of consecutive integers
>   that includes $0$ be realized by some curve $C$?

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but why do the numbers need to be consecutive? You can go around any loop more than once. (Perhaps you are just imposing consecutiveness for simplicity?)

Comment: @ZachTeitler: "the winding numbers for any two adjacent regions differ by exactly 1; the region with the larger winding number appears on the left side of the curve." This from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number#Alexander_numbering).

Comment: Ah, the curve is forbidden from retracing itself. Okay.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Isn't this easy by induction? Delete one of the largest numbers, say $m$, from your sequence, realize the remaining numbers, then in the realization pick any region with winding number $m-1$, and make an extra loop somewhere close to its boundary.

Comment: Simple, clean, and convincing!

Comment: Also works for the signed version of the question by looping either clockwise or counter-.

Comment: Naively, how about for a higher-dimensional version, such as in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/259054/generalization-of-winding-number-to-higher-dimensions ?

Comment: @ZachTeitler: Thanks, Zach, that's where I was heading next... Perhaps a future question.

Comment: I don't see why that would require a different solution, you can just do the same thing.