# Patterns in local winding number sequences

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, discrete-geometry, plane-geometry

This is something of a followup to an earlier question
[Can any sequence of consecutive integers be realized as winding numbers?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/289652/6094), whose answer is *Yes*.

Now I would like to define a local winding number for a
plane curve as follows. For any region $R$ delimited by arcs of a plane curve $C$, define the *local winding number* as the number of counterclockwise arcs bounding $R$ minus the number of clockwise arcs bounding $R$.
It might be easiest to assume that two arcs that meet cross there, so tangencies
are excluded.

---

[image: LocalWindingNumber]

---

As @ZachTeitler observed in a preliminary (now deleted) version of the question,
"the sum of all the local winding numbers [must be] $0$, because each arc counts $+1$ on one side and $-1$ on the other." Indeed in the example above, the sum
is zero.

My question is:

> ***Q***. Are there any other constraints to the sequence of local winding numbers
>   defined by a plane curve?

I've explored a bit without seeing clear patterns, except
for classes of regimented curves, e.g.:

---

[image: Local888]

---

Comment: Without allowing the curve to retrace itself, I doubt you could ever get $-2,2$. With only one curve, I doubt you could ever get $-1,-1,2$ (though it's easy enough with two curves).

Comment: I think that more regularity conditions need to be introduced to rule out degenerate cases; my suggestion would be to require that in a periodic parametric equation of the curve there should be a bijection between $t$ and $(x(t),y(t),x'(t),y'(t))$ because otherwise qualitatively new behavior can be encountered e.g. a set of circles with a common point and at least one of them on each side of the common tangent - then one could trace out the circles in any randomly assignable set of direction, which will have interesting consequences for the local winding numbers.