# Can a topological cat count the number of yarn windings around a ball?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, soft-question, differential-topology

This is a follow-up question to my [previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/297437/is-there-a-sensible-notion-of-a-winding-number-of-a-closed-curve-in-mathbbr) on "winding numbers" of curves in higher-dimensional space. I thought it best to post a new question rather than changing the setup of the previous one from the ground... The comments and answers there suggest that in this case the point of view (pun intended) shouldn't be a point, but really a higher-dimensional object. So, what we are really looking for is $w(\gamma,X)$, the number of windings of a loop $\gamma$ around an appropriate topological subspace $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ (to be determined).

*Example 1.:* Let $L$ be a line and $X:=C:=\mathbb{D}^2\times L$ a solid cylinder in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Then *intuitively* $w(\gamma,C)$ should be determined by the homotopy class of $[\gamma]$ in $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}^3\setminus C)$. But I believe this example to be misleading.

*Example 2:* Let $X:=\mathbb{S}^2$. *Surely* we can count how many rounds/loops a yarn $\gamma$ makes around $X$, even though $\pi_1(X)=0$. It seems $w(\gamma,X)$ shouldn't always be homotopy-invariant.

> Is there a reasonable way to formalize the intuitive notion of number of windings of a loop $\gamma$ around $X$, where $\gamma\cap X=\emptyset$, for a suitable class of topological spaces $X$?

For instance, in $\mathbb{R}^2$ the classical winding number $w(\gamma,a)$ would correspond to $w(\gamma,C_\varepsilon(a))$ for a small circle around $a$. (It's perhaps that second argument that should always be homotopy-invariant?)

*a cat: NORTH AMERICAN *informal* (especially among jazz enthusiasts) a man.

Comment: Re: the word "surely" in example 2. What should be the winding number of the seam on a baseball?

Comment: @WillieWong: sorry, I am not really familiar with baseball. Could you give another example illustrating your point?

Comment: The stitching on a baseball can be roughly modeled by wrapping a helix around a sphere. For another example, take a circular spring, either as a periodic trajectory on a torus, or as a belt placed on a basketball or rounded cylinder.  What should the answer be in both cases, and why or why not is it not the same, as the spring is the same but its environment is not?  Gerhard "Not Ready To Get Dizzy" Paseman, 2018.04.10.

Comment: (How can you know the word "cat" but not what a baseball look like?) Here's an animation of a baseball  https://www.shutterstock.com/video/clip-6184223-stock-footage-baseball-looping-alpha-channel-included.html  Look at the closed curve corresponding to the red parts.

Comment: @WillieWong: a single picture is better than 1000 words, thanks. To answer your question, *surely* the winding number in this case looks like a $1$ :-)

Comment: @GerhardPaseman: the answer depends on the lenght of the periodic trajectory on the torus and the "width" of the torus: the length of the spring divided by the circumference of the torus tube. (I hope I am being clear.) So, it depends on the geometry, not only on the topology.

Comment: @WillieWong: actually, I think a better answer in this case would be the length of the seam curve divided by the lenght of the great circle. In particular, it might not be an integer.

Comment: If the winding number is always an integer but is not homotopy-invariant, then it must sometimes jump discontinuously when the curve is deformed continuously. It would be interesting to see where such jumps occur.

Comment: @AndreasBlass: I am hoping that it can always be an integer, but at the moment I am not really sure, to be honest.

Comment: @WillieWong: the irony is not lost on me that the word "jazz" has baseball roots :-)

Comment: @GerhardPaseman: actually, for a periodic trajectory on a torus, $\pi_1(\mathbb{T})$ seems to give a satisfactory answer.

Comment: @WillieWong Fantastic answer, fantastic video. Right to the point.

Comment: If you remove a point from a sphere you are back at the planar case. I suspect that is what we do when we count the loops of a yarn around a sphere: remove a pole and count the winding number around the other pole. Or do you have an other intuition? The "surely" doesn't really help... Example 1 can also be brought back to the usual case by projecting on a plane orthogonal to cylinder.

Comment: @MaximeLucas: I think you might be onto something with projecting to the plane. If we apply your approach to the torus example, we simply cut the torus to make a cylinder and project the curve to a plane (thus identifying both ends of the curve where the cut was made)? I am a little worried that the examples so far, especially in $\mathbb{R}^3$, might be a tad misrepresentative.